# ¿Cómo recargar el navegador de una sesión desde el servidor?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Muy buenas. Estoy utilizando Django 3.

Si en una computadora particular, se inicia sesión con una cuanta especifica, ¿es posible, desde el servidor, recargar el navegador en donde esta activa esa cuenta?

Para poner por ejemplo:

- En la PC_A, se inicia sesión con la cuenta `VISOR_A` y se muestra un listado cualquiera.
- En algún momento del día, el administrador de la base de datos, actualiza datos.
- **El servidor recarga el navegador de la PC_A donde esta activa la sesión con la cuenta `VISOR_A` y se muestra el listado actualizado**

La idea aquí, es que en la PC_A solo sirve para mostrar contenido, pero no la esta utilizando ningún usuario, solamente el administrador del sistema es el que inicia sesión y deja la PC A funcionando.

**Gracias**

Answer (score 1):

Para realizar la tarea que propones tienes dos alternativas:

- Implementar una llamada Ajax que se ejecute de forma recurrente.
- Utilizar WebSockets. En este último caso, te recomiendo la extensión Django Channels. En su documentación tienes varios tutoriales que podrían ayudarte.

https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/